# What is the use of specifying algorithm in header part of JSON Web Token(JWT)?

Tags: json, algorithm, oauth, token, jwt

I was reading about JWT in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/introduction/). I see that JWT is constructed with header, claims and signing(encrypting) it with a secret key by an algorithm. Header part basically contains the algorithm and type.

Header: `{ "alg": "HS256", "typ": "JWT"}`

While decryption on the resource(application) server, we already knew what is the algorithm used by the authentication server to sign(encrypt) the token, only then we can decrypt the token and get the header and claims part of JWT. As we should already know the algorithm used by the auth server to decrypt it, I don't see any purpose of adding algorithm in header part of JWT.

**EDIT - Rephrasing the question** - Only after we decrypt the token, we would know what is the algorithm used to encrypt the token but in order to decrypt itself, we need to know the algorithm used

Can someone please explain the purpose of specifying algorithm in header part of JWT?

Comment: It is there for explicitness: so that different parties that exchange with JWTs did not guess. Also, it is there for forward compatibility: if you change the algorithm one day - you don't want all the valid tokens to instantly invalidate. PS: "only then we can decrypt the token" --- if you just sign the token - it's not encrypted and is basically plain text.

Comment: @zerkms - I understand. Only after we decrypt the token, we would know what is the algorithm used to encrypt the token. In order to decrypt itself, we need to know the algorithm used. That's where my confusion is. If we change the algorithm in future, then we should try decrypting the token with old algo 1st and then with current algo used to encrypt. If this is the case also, we don't need algo in header.

Comment: It's a common approach and almost every (or every at all?) public serialisation format includes meta information that carries encoding properties. You are free to implement a derived standard that does not include the header. PS: as I mentioned before, in most widely used cases the token is not encrypted, but just signed.